# Boot (possibly MBR) messed up after updating from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

now, before you tell me to use the search function for this (common) issue - i did work an this for the last 5 hours and i am getting to no (close) solution.

This is the exact problem:
After updating my 12.04 to 14.04 yesterday booting ended up in the GRUB rescue prompt. So i did what i did often before when facing boot problems (and it worked every time until yesterday!): i got a live usb-device installed and ran `boot-repair` but this time this made it worse: my bios is now not even recognizing the hard-drive (SATA) as bootable.

Running `boot-repair` a few times more with different settings did not help. Then i searched all the forums and wikis on how to install grub manually and what i found was this:

1. boot into a live system
2. mount the 'broken' system, especially the /sys, /proc and /dev directories
3. chroot into this system
4. (re-)install the correct grub-package (which is grub-efi-amd64 for me)
5. run `update-grub`
6. exit the chroot
7. reboot

But this still leaves me with my hard-drive not beeing recognized (and as a result with a "operating system not found" error)

. The partitioning is the following:

```
/dev/sd?
  /dev/sd?1: 94MB, flags: boot, fat16
  /dev/sd?2: 2GB, linux-swap
  /dev/sd?3: ~260GB, ext4, the rest of the ubuntu 14.04
```

As of my naive view, i always thought this is the way it works:

1. My bios sees the hard-drive and the partition with the boot flag
2. The bios (whether efi or legacy does not matter to me, it has to work) launches grub there
3. Grub loads the linux-kernel from the third partition

I insist on the separate boot-partition because - as i said - this is not the first time for me to experience big issues with GRUB. The separate partition made solving it easier for me.

I'll - of course - provide any information neccessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the boot-repair cd: [Download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair) PS: There is a search, you can use it to find more problems like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `grub-install` you need to run, not `update-grub`, which just rebuilds the menu.  Since it looks like you are using efi, you also have to mount the efi system partition in /boot/efi before you chroot into your root partition.

Comment: `sudo mkdir /tempfs`, `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /tempsys`, `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /tempsys/boot/efi`, `sudo mount -o bind /sys /tempsys/sys` (same for /proc and /dev), `sudo chroot /tempsys`, `sudo apt-get remove --purge grub-efi-amd64`, `sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64` (complains that /dev/pts is not mounted), `sudo grub-install --force /dev/sdb1`, `update-grub`. Success!! Thank you very much! My mistake was to mount /dev/sdb1 to /boot instead of /boot/efi (what prevented grub-install from doing it's job).

Answer (score 0):

The procedure i posted above is not correct in detail. I assume this only works for (U)EFI boot:

1. boot into a live system
2. mount the 'broken' system, especially the /sys, /proc and /dev directories
3. If a separated boot-parition is to be used, mount it to /boot/efi
4. chroot into the mounted system
5. (re-)install the correct grub-package (which is grub-efi-amd64 for me)
6. run `grub-install --force` with the boot partition as parameter (e.g. `grub-install /dev/sdb1`)
7. run update-grub
8. exit the chroot
9. reboot